# tricking typescript compiler to assign wrong-interface to a variable

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to enforce a custom type-rule by abusing typescript.
I've got it working with classes, but I'm having trouble doing it for interfaces. 
Here's the classes version that works:

```
export class HeaderElement extends WebElement { 
  // 'dummy' type: won't create any instances of it at runtime.
  // type-filler member that doesn't exist in other WebElement.
  _HEADER_ELEMENT_TYPE_FILLER_6897689FSAFDSF: string; 
  //  -> dummy member: not even read/written/set in code.
}
const export function getHeaderElement(): HeaderElement {
  // findElement: returns WebElement type
  const header = browser.findElement( ... );
  return header as HeaderElement; 
  // **tricking typescript (actual runtime type would be 'WebElement')**
}
export function clickWowPageMenu(
  headerElem: HeaderElement
  // (headerElem's runtime-type is WebElement. 
  // It's 'HeaderElem' only in compilation phase.)
) { ... }
const headerElem = getHeaderElement();
const saveButtonElem = getSaveButtonElement();
clickWowPageMenu( headerElem ); // ok
clickWowPageMenu( saveButtonElem ); // type-error.
```

But for interfaces version, the following code results in typescript type error:

```
interface IContext {
   __EXTENDS_IContextElem123124: string,
}
interface IChatContext extends IContext {
   name: string,
}
const test: IChatContext = { name: 'namehere' } as IChatContext;
// want: no type error here. (but 'missing __EXTENDS_IContextElem123124')
const test2: IChatContext = {} as IChatContext;
// want: type error here. (missing property 'name')
```

How do I 'abuse' typescript to type-check interfaces the way I want? Or is there some other way (eg. something official)?

Thank you!

----------------EDITS---------
1. sorry for the typo

```
const test: IContextElem ... --> IContext
```

2. add missing details (wants / want-nots)

Answer (score 1):

The TypeError is correct because you have `IContextElem` instead of `IContext`.

After changing that your example compiles again in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IContext%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20__EXTENDS_IContextElem_TYPE_FILLER123124%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20IChatContext%20extends%20IContext%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20name%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20test%3A%20IContext%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20'namehere'%20%7D%20as%20IChatContext)

Comment: huh? I guess yours does work... but I had errors saying "__EXTENDS_IContextElem_TYPE_FILLER123124 doesn't exist on IContextElem" but...those are gone!

Comment: wait... your solution is ok with: ```const test: IChatContext = {} as IChatContext``` ... so I guess that's not 100% what I wanted... sorry